# ¿Como aceptar HTML en FULL CALENDAR?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

estoy trabajando con full calendar Jquery
Este es mi código, quiero agregar unos iconos en la descripción o titulo del calendario, pero al momento de mostrar los datos me sale como texto y quisiera que saliera como html para que detecte mi etiqueta `<i>`

```
function loadCalendar() {   
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'destroy' );  $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        {
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
        header:
        {
          left: 'prev,next',//today
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
        },
        monthNames: ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre" ],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
        dayNames: [ 'Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Jue','Vie','Sáb'],
        buttonText: {
            today: 'Hoy',
            month: 'Mes',
            week: 'Semana',
            day: 'Día',
            list: 'Lista',
        },
        weekNumbers: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: 'api.php',
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view)
            {
              viewAct(calEvent);
            }   });   $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' ); }
```

Después recorro mi consulta

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{

$titulohus=utf8_encode($row['ca_desc']);
$titulohus=substr($titulohus,0,15);
$tit=ucwords(strtolower($titulohus));

  $i++;
  $jsa[] =array(
      'id' => $row['ca_id'],
            'title' =>' <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$tit,
            'start' =>$row['ca_fecha'],
            'url' => "",
            'className' => $lk,
            'color'=>$color,
            'allDay'=> false

  );
}
echo json_encode($jsa);
```

Cuando despliego los datos me sale de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saben que me hace falta??

Comment: ¿Que versión de `fullcalendar` estas usando?

Comment: @Marcos la 3.10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes conseguirlo usando [`eventRender`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventRender)

> Se ejecuta cuando se procesa un evento. Un gancho para modificar su DOM.

#### Ejemplo

```js
$(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
    },
    locale: 'es',
    eventRender: function(info, $el) {
      // ACA ponemos el titulo como HTML
      $el.find('.fc-title').html(info.title);
    },
    events: [{
      title: '<i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reunion',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 30),
      location: "Aca",
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: '<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Otra reunion',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 13, 30),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 30),
      location: "Alla",
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: '<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Otra vez otra reunion',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 15, 30),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 16, 30),
      location: "Por ahí",
      allDay: false
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.0/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/locale/es.js'></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```